# Creating a function that returns cash from funds in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm attempting to create a function that returns coins after an item has been purchased. I'm not finished, but the code below is an attempt to find the number of quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies that should be returned:

```
 public String getChange(VendingMachine vendingMachine, Change change) {

    double dispensedQuarters = 0;
    double dispensedDimes = 0;
    double dispensedNickels = 0;
    double dispensedPennies = 0;
    double d = Double.parseDouble(vendingMachine.getFunds());

    if (d % .25 == 0) {
        dispensedQuarters = d / .25;
    } else if (d % .25 != 0) {
        double remainder = d % .25;
        d = d - remainder;
        dispensedQuarters = d / .25;

        if (remainder % .10 == 0) {
            dispensedDimes = remainder / .10;
        } else if (remainder % .05 == 0) {
            dispensedNickels = remainder / .05;
        } else if (remainder % .01 == 0) {
            dispensedPennies = remainder / .01;
        } else {
            dispensedDimes = dispensedNickels = dispensedPennies = 0;
        }

    } else if (d % .10 == 0) {
        dispensedDimes = d / .10;
    } else if (d % .05 == 0) {
        dispensedNickels = d / .10;
    }
}
```

Is there a more compact way of creating a function that will find the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies that should be returned?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using floating point values to represent currencies.  Use integers, where any amount that is not a multiple of 100 is the 'cents' part.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make note of that.

Comment: What should the machine return? The least number of coins?

Comment: Yes, the least number of coins.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this more elegantly by using `enum`s.

- Just create the different `Coin` objects using an `enum`, and add the value in the constructor. Make sure the `enum` instances are in descending order.

  ```
  enum Coin {

      QUARTER(25), DIME(10), NICKEL(5), PENNY(1);

      private final int value;

      private Coin(int value) {
          this.value = value;
      }

      public int getValue() {
          return this.value;
      }
  }
  ```
- Then iterate over all different types of coins, and subtract as many coins from the change amount until the remaining value is smaller than the coin value.

  ```
  private List<Coin> getCoins(int value) {
      List<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<>();

      // Loop over all different kind of coins, starting with the coin
      // with the highest value
      for (Coin coin : Coin.values()) {
          // For each kind, subtract the coin value as many times as
          // possible, then advance to the next coin.
          while (value >= coin.getValue()) {
              value -= coin.getValue();
              coins.add(coin);
          }
      }
      return coins;
  }
  ```

Example code:

```
getCoins(95);
// returns a list with 3 quarters and 2 dimes.
```

---

*The abovementioned code does indeed return the least number of coins — at least in this case. But note that it does not necessarily in all cases. There are cases where it's better to return more coins of a lower value, instead of ones of a higher value.

For example, if you have the coins `TWELVY` (value 12), `DIME` (value 10), `NICKEL` (value 5) and `PENNY` (value 1), and the change would be 45, the least number of coins would be 5 (4 dimes and 1 penny) instead of 8 (3 twelvies, 1 nickel and 4 pennies).*

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with some of this code.

`if (remainder % .10 == 0) {`

This only tells you if you could pay the entire rest of your coins out in dimes - it does not tell you if you need a dime or two.  For example, if remainder was 0.23 this condition would be false, even though you should be paying two dimes.

`} else if (remainder % .05 == 0) {`

Same issue.  If you had 0.07 left to pay, this condition would be false, but it would still be appropriate to pay a nickel.

`else if (remainder % .01 == 0) {`

This check seems unneeded, and getting rid of it could make your code more compact.  This will *always* be true, unless you have fractions of a penny for some reason.  (This could be due to rounding errors, which, as was pointed out in the comments, could be avoided by using integers.)

Answer (score 0):

Caution: calculateChange - takes number of cents as a parameter

```
public class QuarterDimeNickelPenny {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        calculateChange(94); // Should be 3, 1, 1, 4
        calculateChange(50); // Should be 2, 0, 0, 0
        calculateChange(30); // Should be 1, 0, 1, 0
        calculateChange(14); // Should be 0, 1, 0, 4
        calculateChange(69); // Should be 2, 1, 1, 4
        calculateChange(75); // Should be 3, 0, 0, 0
    }


    private static void calculateChange(int cents) {
        int quarters = cents / 25;
        int leftover = cents - quarters * 25;
        int dimes = leftover / 10;
        leftover = leftover - dimes * 10;
        int nickels = leftover / 5;
        leftover = leftover - nickels * 5;
        int pennies = leftover;

        System.out.println(quarters + ", " + dimes + ", " + nickels + ", " + pennies);
    }

}
```

Try this, hope this helps